# How to add Horizontal scrolling property in table using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing a site in PHP, I have to display the data in table, I can't display whole data on that table since the table is large and my div is so small, so I decided to add a scroller in left side and right side of table. I have added the image of table. How can I scroll the table using Javascript or jQuery?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: css is enough to add scroller:
`overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: @vimalnath How can i implement this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use the `scroll` in css like this:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow) for a demo

Or you could use the [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) Plugin in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqgrid which provide much extra functionality with table view.

Go through this -
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

by using this line  of code in your table OR div tag which you are use

i.e.

```
<table style="overflow-x: scroll;">
....
</table>

<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">
....
</div >
```

hope it will work for you